# getting factors from a column dataset

Tags: r

i have a R dataset with a column "location_type". *Location type :List of 15057*

```
head(ds $ location_type)

[[1]]
[1] "store"

[[2]]
[1] "store"     "service"

[[3]]
[1] "store"     "service"

[[4]]
[1] "store"     "service"     "regular appointment"
```

im trying to convert these values to factors since right now they are showing as a list inside that variable so i get the following factors

store
store service
store service regular appointment

this function yields only but NA's

```
ds$location_type1 <- factor(ds$location_type, levels=c("store","store service","store service regular appointment"))
```

i will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `location_type` is a list, we can `paste` all the individual element in it to create a single value which can be converted to `factor`.

```
ds$location_type <- factor(sapply(ds$location_type, paste, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: thanks. it didnt work since the unlist will separate **store service regular appointment** into 3 additional values ...
`Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, location_type1, value = c("store",  : `
`replacement has 24586 rows, data has 15057`

Comment: @AndresMora Try `ds$location_type <- factor(sapply(ds$location_type, paste, collapse = " "))`

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
ds %>%
   mutate(location_type = factor(map_chr(location_type, str_c, collapse=" ")))
```